# Bent Knee Deadlift replacement

Tags: injury-prevention

What exercise can replace bent knee deadlifts?

My main goal is to strengthen my glutes to prevent lower back injury (I tore some muscles in my lower back years ago).

I've been getting subtle lower back pangs when performing the exercise with two 12kg dumbbells. I think carrying my son on my shoulders and bad form may have flaired up the old injury.

I am doing the following exercise group:

- barbell squats (25kg-30kg)
- bent knee deadlifts (two 12kg dumbbells)
- bench side leg raises

What exercise can I do instead of bent knee deadlifts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main focus in doing bent knee deadlifts is strengthening your glutes, some other glute-focus exercises would be good options to replace it. These can be exercises such as glute bridges, hip thrusts, or abductors. These reduce a lot of back strain and focus mainly on isolating and strengthening the glute muscles.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Since you are already incorporating barbell squats (I assume back-squats) in your regimen, I think substituting deadlifts is a good option. I usually will do either squats or deadlifts on a leg day, but not both in order to lower the amount of volume and not overkill my knees and lower back.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

If your OK with barbell squat, good mornings are a similar but glute focused exercise:
[image]